# Running NodeJS from Python

Tags: python, node.js

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to run NodeJS from Python. I have no problems running ShellScript from Python and NodeJS from ShellScript, but can't seem to get NodeJS from Python, I just get the following output:

```
b"
```

These are the simplified version of my scripts.

NodeJS I am trying to run from within Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("Hello " + process.argv[2]);
```

And here is the Python, using Python3.

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
import os
import re
import sys
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = subprocess.Popen(['/Users/Brett/scripts/hello.js', 'Brett'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out = p.stdout.read()
        print(out)
```

Thanks for the help! Much appreciated.

EDITS:
I have no issue executing the following from the commandline, as 'hello.js' is executable:

```
hello.js 'Brett'
```

`shell=true` does not fix it.

Additionally, I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.5 and therefore my shell is zsh.

If I add `node` to the front of the command, I get no such file or directory for `node`, I tried it as follows:
`p = subprocess.Popen(['/Users/Brett/scripts/hello.js', 'Brett'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: You're reading the wrong argument from argv. If you were calling it like this `node hello.js Brett` *then* it would be the third element in argv, but since you used the hashbang and are calling it like a script it would be the *second* (at index 1) argument. You can see how this fails by calling it without python directly in the shell: `cd /Users/Brett/scripts; ./hello.js Brett`. Either specify node in the python subprocess call `Popen(["node", "/Users/Brett/scripts/hello.js", "Brett"])` or change the index into sys.argv to 1.

Comment: At least on Linux I don't think that is true.
```bash
$ node ./hello.js Brett
Hello Brett
[ '/usr/bin/node', '/tmp/so/1/hello.js', 'Brett' ]
$ chmod +x hello.js
$ ./hello.js Brett
Hello Brett
[ '/usr/bin/node', '/tmp/so/1/hello.js', 'Brett' ]
```

Comment: @MaxStanley hmmm, I'll test it. Given the uppercase Users in the path though I'd assume OP is on MacOS, in which case my fix will definitely work. I'm spinning up a vagrant VM right now to check.

Comment: you need to run "node /Users/Brett/scripts/hello.js" at least if you want it to run in node enviorment

Comment: @Talg123 why? OP put a hashbang at the start of the file.

Comment: I dusted off my mac and tried to duplicate this and I can't.  As posted, it works fine for me-- tested with High Sierra 10.13.6, python3 via homebrew.  However, @JaredSmith seems to be able to duplicate it.  My guess is that maybe you guys are using a different shell.  Don't really know.  As I mentioned in Jared's answer, I would try adding a shell=True to the Popen call (Popen(['/Users/.../hello.js', 'Brett'], shell=True) and seeing if that helps.  Since you're relying on a shebang, the shell=True is probably appropriate to have in there no matter the OS.

Comment: I have no issue executing the following from the command-line, as `hello.js` is executable:
`hello.js 'Brett'`

Additionally, I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.5 and therefore my shell is zsh.

Comment: shell=True does not help.

Comment: @clockwatcher I can replicate on Catalina in fish and zsh (default interactive shell kn the new OS). Ubuntu 18.04 VM via vagrant has the expected behavior. Interesting that High Sierra doesn't replicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after doing some testing based on the comments by Max Stanley:

There is an inconsistency between Linux and MacOS here about the population of the argv array. On Mac you will want the second index (1) and on Linux you will want the third (2).

I recommend using a command-line argument parser like [command-line-args](https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-args) which should paper over the platform differences.

In the meantime you can specify node in the python subprocess call Popen(["node", "/Users/Brett/scripts/hello.js", "Brett"]) which has the same behavior on both.

Comment: Since you have a system where you seem to be able to duplicate what's been posted.  Would you mind checking if adding a shell=True to the Popen call fixes things?

Comment: shell=True does not fix it. Adding node, gets me no such file or directory for 'node'. I tried it as follows:
`p = subprocess.Popen(['node', '/Users/Brett/scripts/hello.js', 'Brett'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: You an change `'node'` to the path where nodejs is installed on your system.

Comment: You can use `shutil.which()` to find `node`.

Comment: @Brett max stanley and paulie4 are correct.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks everyone for the responses. All were super helpful. Especially @max-stanley and @jared-smith.

The following ended up working for me:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/node', '/Users/Brett/scripts/hello.js', 'Brett'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = p.stdout.read()
print(out)
```

Not sure why it doesn't work with the shebang in the executable js file but I am not committed to it, so I will just take the working solution and move on. ;-)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Having tested this on my system, it looks as though you need to either make the hello.js file executable `chmod +x ./hello.js` or you need to add 'node' to the beginning of the Popen argument list as @Jared had said.

Comment: Yeah, but if the file isn't executable you'd get an error?

Comment: If you didn't add node to the beginning of the Popen argument list yes you would get an error.

Comment: So why would adding the executable bit matter if you're specifying the executable?

Comment: It wouldn't, I was giving OP the choice, you could either made the .js file executable so that it is run using the environment set in the #! at the top of the file, or you could run the file using node in the Popen argument list, or you could do both,

Comment: 'hello.js' was already executable. And I can execute it directly from the command line without issue.